# Java: Interface with Subclass

Tags: java

I am using an interface with a subclass. I'm getting a no of errors:

> Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token
>   Multiple markers at this line
>       - Method breakpoint:TestSubClass [entry] - 
>        doSomething(String)
>       - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
>       - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
>       - implements TestInterface.doSomething
>   Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

From my code I thought I had implemented everything OK. It is lokking fo an extra `}` and I can't see why. I have called `super()` correctly I think but still errors around the doSomething method. Any hints?

```
public interface TestInterface {    
   public void doSomething (String text);    
} 

public class TestBaseClass { 

    private String name;     

    public TestBaseClass() {

    }       

    public TestBaseClass(String name){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;    
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;   
    } 
} 

public class TestSubClass extends TestBaseClass implements TestInterface {  

    super(name);    

    public void doSomething (String text){

    } 
}
```

Comment: Start by indenting your code properly, which will make it much more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestSubClass extends TestBaseClass implements TestInterface{   
   public TestSubClass(String name) {
      super(name); 
   }

   public void doSomething (String text){
   } 
}
```

You can't just call `super(name);` in the class, it has to be inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The `super(name);` can't exist by itself inside the `TestSubClass`. Where's the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestSubClass extends TestBaseClass implements TestInterface{   
    //This should be called inside a constructor 
    super(name);


    //Ok here 
    public void doSomething (String text){} 
}
```

Do like this:

```
public class TestSubClass extends TestBaseClass implements TestInterface{   
    public TestSubClass (){ 
       super(name);
    }

    public void doSomething (String text){} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kayaman implied, you need a constructor definition to delegate to the constructor of the superclass:

```
public class TestSubClass extends TestBaseClass implements TestInterface{   

  public TestSubClass(String name){
       super(name); 

  }


public void doSomething (String text){
} 
}
```